# jQuery AJAX and PHP session issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Really hope this makes sense and someone can  point me in right direction. On a registration page (parent page), when you enter a license code a jQuery ajax success function loads content from another page with an appended url to include a session id:

```
success: function(data) {
    if (data=="RegisterError") {
        $("#error").show();
        $("#processing").hide();
    } else {
        $("#contain").load("download-software.php?sessionid=xXXX #req");
        }
    }
```

The page "download-software" has the following PHP referrer check to make sure the content is being requested from the registration page via the session ID and redirects you if it's not:

```
<?php
$code = $_GET['sessionid'];
if(strcmp( $code , 'xXXX'  ) != 0) {
    header("Location: http://www.someotherpage.com");
}
?>
```

That works fine. Now what I need to do is in the "download-software #req" content that is loaded into the parent page, have a link that when clicked replaces the "download-software #req" content which has been loaded inside the parent page with content from another page and do the same type of session id check.

I cannot get it to work. I place the following code on the "download-software #req" content for the 
`<a id="beta"`>beta notes 
$("#beta").click(function() {
              $("#req").load("NT7-SP1-Download.php #betaNotes");
          });`

I've also tried using the .live function. How do I start a new session and make this work?
******answer*******
I used the live function on the parent page and it works fine. Making it too hard i guess.

Comment: You might want to use Amazon S3 for this. You can generate a URL that is only valid for N minutes on successful authorization and just hand it to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would refrain from using GET query string parameters and use the included PHP session functions.

use:

```
<?php

// initialize the session 
session_start();

// assignment call
$_SESSION['key'] = 'value';

?>
```

You can retrieve data from the session on the same server in subsequent page requests.

When you are done with the session, use: session_destroy()